# Use synonyms in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am trying to implement synonyms file in my search implementation. I found many documents as guidelines for implementing that but could not end up with a working solution.

First, I have added the analyzer as follows:

```
PUT /products/_settings
{
    "settings": {
        "index" : {
            "analysis" : {
                "analyzer" : {
                    "synonym" : {
                        "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
                        "filter" : ["synonym"]
                    }
                },
                "filter" : {
                    "synonym" : {
                        "type" : "synonym",
                        "synonyms_path" : "analysis/synonym.txt"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I was trying to use this synonym analyzer like the following:

```
GET products/_search
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "television",
            "fields": ["prd_name","brand_name", "prd_sdescription"],
            "analyzer": "synonym"
        }
    }
}
```

I have the synonym as solr format like:

```
GB,gib,gigabyte,gigabytes
MB,mib,megabyte,megabytes
Television, Televisions, TV, TVs
```

But the search gets nothing for television while I have records for TV.

I also tried to search single field (prd_name) with synonym match, for that I need to change the but getting error when I want to change the mapping of the prd_name field.

```
"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason": "Mapper for [prd_name] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [prd_name] has different [analyzer]]"
```

The current mapping of prd_name is:

```
"prd_name": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      }
    }
}
```

If someone could give me step by step solution that would be great for me.

```
Elasticsearch version: 6.4.1
```

Comment: did you create a new mapping after you changed the analyzer, can you ping the output of `_mapping` ES api ?

Comment: Could you please provide also the band_name field mapping? Thanks

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal 
I tried to add the analyzer mapping to prd_name field but getting error as mentioned.

Comment: @Lupanoide 
Here is the brand_name mapping: 
"brand_name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1: Requires change in custom analyzer created and adding that in field name

**Point 1: Add lowercase tokenizer in mapping**

[Whitespace](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-tokenizer.html) tokenizer *would not* convert the tokens into lowercase. And in the list of synonyms, you have added `'Television'` but you are querying `'television'`.

Add [Lowercase Token Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html) in your mapping as follows and your query would give you the expected result.

**Point 2: Add analyzer to the field-name**

Check the `prd_name` as how I've created in the below mapping. Notice that I've added analyzer to it.

**Mapping**

```
PUT products
{  
   "settings":{  
      "index":{  
         "analysis":{  
            "analyzer":{  
               "synonym":{  
                  "tokenizer":"whitespace",
                  "filter":[  
                     "synonym",
                     "lowercase"
                  ]
               }
            },
            "filter":{  
               "synonym":{  
                  "type":"synonym",
                  "synonyms_path":"analysis/synonym.txt"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings":{  
      "mydocs":{  
         "properties":{  
            "prd_name":{  
               "type":"text",
               "analyzer":"synonym",
               "fields":{  
                  "keyword":{  
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Note that any mapping change would require you to *recreate* the index and *ingest* the documents again.

Make sure that your synonym file is available in all the nodes.

Let me know if it helps.

### Solution 2: Redefine default analyzer

In case if you are not able to change the mapping of the field, what you can do is, create an analyzer with name `default` in the settings

Basically *redefining the `default` analyzer with settings exactly as analyzer `synonym`.*

That way it would be the default analyzer that'd be used instead of `standard` analyzer and requires no change in the mapping of field name.

Below is how the mapping would be in that case.

**Mapping**

```
PUT <your_index_name>
{  
   "settings":{  
      "index":{  
         "analysis":{  
            "analyzer":{  
               "default":{  
                  "tokenizer":"whitespace",
                  "filter":[  
                     "synonym",
                     "lowercase"
                  ]
               }
            },
            "filter":{  
               "synonym":{  
                  "type":"synonym",
                  "synonyms_path":"analysis/synonym.txt"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings":{  
      "mydocs":{  
         "properties":{  
            "prd_name":{  
               "type":"text",
               "fields":{  
                  "keyword":{  
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Note that I've simply renamed `synonym` to `default` in the mapping.

**Important Note:** Somehow you would need to reindex all the data for the changes to be in effect. In case if you do come up with having to change mapping, reindex all data, and you can do anything you'd want w.r.t field names, then I strongly suggest solution 1.

Let me know if this helps :)

Comment: I have added the lowercase filter as well, but it does not work (tried for multi_match). Cannot change the mapping for prd_name, it shows the error mentioned in question.

Comment: In that case what you can do is change the values in the `synonyms.txt`, put everything into lowercase and give it a try. Let me know if that works out. Ideally I would want you to make use of `prd_name` with analyzer `synonym` but this is the only workaround I can think of right now. Keep me posted if that works out.

Comment: @Mainuddin any luck?

Comment: No, case is not a problem here. The problem is- I cannot change the mapping of prd_name field to include the synonym filter.

Comment: @Mainuddin Could you please check the `solution 2` in the answer I've just updated. :)

Comment: But if I make the default analyzer synonym, won't it be applied to all field by default? I don't want to apply synonyms to all fields, want only for one or two fields.

Comment: Yes that's true. Unfortunately the only, in that case,  is to implement solution 1.